# One of the mongo shards consuming too much disk space.

Tags: disk-space, sharding, mongodb-3.4

We have mongo cluster with 10 shards of each having 3 replicas.
Recently we are facing an issue, exceptionally in a couple of shards, the disk space among all the 3 replicas has reached above 90%.

Can someone help me why this will happen with mongo cluster?

Thanks in advance.